# How to create a tooltip on hover over this li ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

really need your help, I have the following code for a list being used on filter plugin on my website. I'm trying to have a **tooltip** show up with brief text when a services name is hovered, **Adult Day Program Services**, **Clinical Services**, **Community & Socialization**, etc.

They all share the same class **"sf-level-0"** which makes it confusing to me? how else can I target each item on this list to show a text tooltip when each service name is hovered please?

```html
<ul data-operator="or" class="">

    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Adult Day Program Services" name="_sfm_service_type[]"
            id="sf-input-e6bc565b2d96339dcf959e2a1e3561d8"><label class="sf-label-checkbox"
            for="sf-input-e6bc565b2d96339dcf959e2a1e3561d8">Adult Day Program Services</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Clinical Services" name="_sfm_service_type[]" id="sf-input-ffb6f68d490778d1cd1fc48061179fd8"><label
            class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-ffb6f68d490778d1cd1fc48061179fd8">Clinical Services</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Community &amp; Socialization" name="_sfm_service_type[]"
            id="sf-input-a9f73ee6bc24adcb64e50714f67efb34"><label class="sf-label-checkbox"
            for="sf-input-a9f73ee6bc24adcb64e50714f67efb34">Community &amp; Socialization</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Education" name="_sfm_service_type[]" id="sf-input-a038069c980c3056538c3df18c13e8d8"><label
            class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-a038069c980c3056538c3df18c13e8d8">Education</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Employment Support" name="_sfm_service_type[]" id="sf-input-79a2489689ae03b5d8077f27e91cbec3"><label
            class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-79a2489689ae03b5d8077f27e91cbec3">Employment Support</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Family Support" name="_sfm_service_type[]" id="sf-input-afc695061514a6bad64a2606576981c8"><label
            class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-afc695061514a6bad64a2606576981c8">Family Support</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Living Opportunities" name="_sfm_service_type[]"
            id="sf-input-e3709d92816676e3513fd243acc6181d"><label class="sf-label-checkbox"
            for="sf-input-e3709d92816676e3513fd243acc6181d">Living Opportunities</label></li>
    <li class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"
            value="Technology" name="_sfm_service_type[]" id="sf-input-bd2d76ad601550486e4d52b3d0fb09f4"><label
            class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-bd2d76ad601550486e4d52b3d0fb09f4">Technology</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What you want to target if you want to target label on these names you can give ul a class and then use .class  label:hover toottiptext something

Comment: again,  I can't change the code above as it's a code generated by a WordPress plugin. The only thing I can do is create an additional custom code to target what I need. Not sure if this will ever work ?? If you can show what you mean let me know

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [TippyJS](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/constructor/)

You can use the data attributes to set the tooltip text and use the specific constructor to initialize all of them at once.

Comment: I can't change the code above as it's a code generated by a WordPress plugin. The only thing I can do is create an additional custom code to target what I need.  Not sure if this will ever work ??

Comment: You can edit it using js later